# Is there any draft system for Single Types in strapi?

Tags: strapi

I wanted to save draft in strapi for single types without publishing it. Right now if  i save the changes it will be published directly. 
I tried using a boolean - published, and show the data on frontend app when published is true. This way if the published bool is false whole single page data will not be shown. 
I want it so that previous data is still there but not the new unpublished data.

Is there any way to make this achievable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've mentioned it, why not add an `is_draft` boolean type to your strapi model and use that as a `shadow crud` filter when querying the [rest api](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/content-api/parameters.html#available-operators) or [graphql endpoint](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/plugins/graphql.html#query-api)?

If you want to prevent strapi from returning draft records, you can also override the [controller find function](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/controllers.html#core-controllers).

```js
// api/article/controllers/article.js

const { sanitizeEntity } = require('strapi-utils');

module.exports = {

  /**
   * Retrieve records.
   *
   * @return {Array}
   */

  async find(ctx) {
    let entities;
    ctx.query.is_draft = typeof ctx.query.is_draft === 'boolean' ? ctx.query.is_draft || false; // return published by default, or the explicitly specified is_draft filter.
    if (ctx.query._q) {
      entities = await strapi.services.article.search(ctx.query);
    } else {
      entities = await strapi.services.article.find(ctx.query);
    }

    return entities.map(entity => sanitizeEntity(entity, { model: strapi.models.article }));
  },
};
```